# Node.js browser error

Tags: node.js

i am new to Node.js. i followed the tutorial and typed the following

```
var sys = require("util"),
http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.write("Hello World!");
response.close();
}).listen(8080);

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:1331/");
```

but when i go to my browser and type the url i.e. http://localhost:1331
it is failed to open th erequested URL

getting the following in cmd when browse the URL

```
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'sendHeader'
at Server.<anonymous> (D:\node_js\hello.js:11:14)
at Server.emit (events.js:70:17)
at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1511:12)
at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
at Socket.ondata (http.js:1407:22)
at TCP.onread (net.js:354:27)
```

Comment: do i need to setup any web server like apache for this or nodejs sets it up???

Comment: Your node.js application is a web server. So no, you don't need another web server. It seems like you followed a (very) old tutorial, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you followed an out of date tutorial. The Node API has since changed. Try this example:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1331);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1331/');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're listening on port 8080.  Either change your URL or the port number you're passing into listen().

Comment: changed the port in listen() but still there :(

Comment: hmm maybe use netstat or something to make sure it's running on the right port and that no other process is using that port number.

Comment: i have changed many port numbers, it should work on one of them